# In abelian categories, is a right/left exact functor necessarily additive?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I think this is too vague to prove but I don't have any examples that is not additive. Even I have not seen any functors that is not additive.

Comment: Recall that an additive functor $F$ satisfy $F(0)=0$. In particular, the constant functor $F(X)=A$, or the functor $G(X)=X\oplus A$ for a fixed $A$ are not additive. Other examples are $F(X)=X\otimes X$ (which does not preserve direct sum), or the functor which take an abelian group to the free abelian group spanned by its elements...

Comment: @Roland But are they left exact? For example the the constant functor may not provide an exact sequence $A\to A\to A\to0$.

Comment: No this was an example of a non additive functor (you said you have not seen any functors that is not additive). This is why this is just a comment. Ben answered your question : an left/right functor preserve finite limits/colimits, so both preserve the zero object and the direct sum.

Answer (score 4):

A left exact functor preserves finite limits, in particular products, so in particular the biproduct.